# How to make edgesIgnoringSafeArea in swiftUI work?

Tags: swift, swiftui

The following code makes a view where a rectangle is at the bottom of the view. I put `.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)` so the rectangle goes all the way down, but it doesn't work. I'm simulating this on an iPhone 11 and always leaves a blank space below.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                List {
                    Text("Hello, World!")
                }
                
                Spacer()
                
                Rectangle()
                    .frame(height: 150)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rectangle is inside a `VStack`, and the `VStack` doesn't ignore the safe area. Even if the rectangle ignores the safe area, it can't *extend beyond its parent* to fill the whole screen.

You should put `edgesIgnoringSafeArea` after the `VStack`, and the rectangle will naturally fill the `VStack`, hence filling the whole screen.

```
var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        VStack {
            List {
                Text("Hello, World!")
            }
            
            Spacer()
            
            Rectangle()
                .frame(height: 150)
        }
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.edgesIgnoringSafeArea` is deprecated, you can use `.ignoresSafeArea` instead:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Color(.systemTeal)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            Text("I Am Rich")
                .font(.system(size: 40))
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    }
        
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```